# How to pass List of class to List of Interface?

Tags: c#, class, list, interface

I have a function like this:

```
DoSomething(List<IMyInterface>)
```

IMyInterface is an interface and MyClass is a class implementing this interface
Class MyClass:IMyInterface

I call `DoSomething(List<MyClass>)` and it looks it doesn't work.
How could I pass the list of a class to a list of the interface of the class as function's parameter? Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If your code is simply iterating over the sequence inside the method (not adding, removing, or accessing by index), change your method to one of the following

```
DoSomething(IEnumerable<IMyInterface> sequence)
DoSomething<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence) where T : IMyInterface
```

The `IEnumerable<>` interface is covariant (as of .NET 4) (first option). Or you could use the latter signature if using C# 3.

Otherwise, if you need indexed operations, convert the list prior to passing it. In the invocation, you might have

```
// invocation using existing method signature 
DoSomething(yourList.Cast<IMyInterface>().ToList());

// or updating method signature to make it generic
DoSomething<T>(IList<T> list) where T : IMyInterface
```

What the latter signature would allow you to do is to also support adds or removes to the list (visible at the callsite), and it would also let you use the list without first copying it.

Even still, if all you do is iterate over the list in a loop, I would favor a method acceping `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: For indexed operations and removal, wouldn't `DoSomething<T>(IList<T> list) where T : IMyInterface` also work? (Without the need for the list to be copied.)

Comment: @Sli, yes, he could make the method generic. I have updated to show the generic options.

Comment: An alternative would be to define an interface IReadableList<out T>, and then write a wrapper class which implements both that and IList<T>.  Other code would unfortunately have to be changed to use the wrapper class, though.  One could define a widening conversion from a List<T> to a ListWrapper<T>, but that would be somewhat icky and it wouldn't help the system recognize that a List<Dog> can be turned into something (a ListWrapper<Dog>) that implements  IReadableList<Animal>.

Answer (score 16):

This is not safe in general because Lists are mutable. Suppose you pass someone a reference to a `List<MyClass>` as a `List<IMyInterface>`, then they do:

```
void Foo(List<IMyInterface> list)
{
    IMyInterface x = new MyOtherClassWhichAlsoImplementsIMyInterface();
    list.Add(x);
}
```

Now your `List<MyClass>` contains an instance of a class that is not a `MyClass`. This would violate type safety. (As other answers noted, you can avoid this problem by passing only the `IEnumerable<>` interface of List, which provides read-only access and so is safe).

For more details, see [Using Variance in Interfaces for Generic Collections on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465120%28VS.100%29.aspx). See also [a good summary of covariance and contravariance and various C# features that support it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to go through the list, declare the method with an IEnumerable. If you want to add elements to the list, what you're asking isn't typesafe and might not be allowed in C# as a result.